# Spring Boot - custom validation messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can someone please help me?
I'm trying to follow this post(https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-custom-validation-message-source/), to make custom validation messages.
I was confused in part 5, which is defining the properties of the file.
Do I have to create a file exactly with this nomenclature "messages_ {locale} .properties"? Or do I put the messages inside aplication.properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have to configure messages source. Following the tutorial you have to implement bean like this:

```
@Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
      messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
      messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
      return messageSource;
   }
```

Where **classpath:messages** is a base name of messages files placed inside */resource* directory. Therefore, you **must** follow the convention of creating files like messages_{locale}.properties where **locale** means a specific language tag.

For example, assuming you want to handle english and spanish messages, you must create following files: **messages_en.properties** and **messages_es.properties**.

Comment: Thank you very much